# Insertion Sort in python using Key

Tags: python, insertion-sort

```
def insertion_sort2(A):
  for i in range(1,len(A)):
      key = A[i]
      j = i-1
      for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
          if A[j] > key :
              A[j+1] = A[j]
          else:
              A[j+1] = key
              break

  for i in range(1, len(arr)):

    key = arr[i]

    j = i-1
    while j >=0 and key < arr[j] :
        arr[j+1] = arr[j]
        j -= 1
    arr[j+1] = key
```

Hello I have tried both methods to do simple Insertion Sort in c++ it works but in python it is not working,but both of them are giving answers like
1st one:

```
[56, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 99]
```

2nd one: 
    does not sort even

Note:The second one starts after break and I have not run them both together,I commented out one and then run the other one

Comment: Mentioning C++ does not make it a C++ question. Please tag only with what is most relevant to your post. If you click on the tags and visit their wiki pages, there will usually be useful documentation there to help you decide if the tag is appropriate.

Comment: If you do `A[j+i] = key`, then `key` is now in `A[j+1]` and `A[i]`, and whatever value _used_ to be in `A[j+1]` is nowhere. That's why you end up with the number `77` spammed over a bunch of other values: because you're not swapping those other values anywhere, you're just throwing them away.

Comment: Litter your code with print statements or step through with a debugger. At some point you will see a divergence between your expectation and reality. Start debugging at that point. Ask a targeted question if you get stuck on the specific thing you are debugging.

Comment: You have a typo in the second function. it should be `arr[j+1] = key`. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't go upto the 0th element in the array in the inner loop. In python's range function, the range is counted uptil one before the second term. On putting range(i-1,-1,-1) the range becomes i-1 to 0.
Secondly, you are not swapping the two consecutive elements , just assigning (j)th element a value of (j+1)th element. But what about assigning jth value to (j-1)th element.
Third, there's no meaning of doing A[j+1] = key as it already is key.

```
def insertion_sort2(A):
  for i in range(1,len(A)):
      key = A[i]
      j = i-1
      for j in range(i-1,-1,-1):
          if A[j] > key :
              A[j+1], A[j] = A[j], A[j+1]
          else:
              break
```

Comment: you are using different approach for insertion sort I know this approach to swap like that,but I intend to use key ,the key changes each step at A[j+1] = key so it doesn't need swap